# Website changes size in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, resize, height

The site I am designing dramatically changes size for me when I open it in Chrome (as opposed to Firefox and Internet Explorer). On my computer it becomes almost half the size it should be. I've looked at it on another computer which showed it, not as bad, but still small.

Here's the site: dinneronthespot.com

I've never seen this type of problem in previous sites I've made, so I'm not sure why this is happening. I've also made sure that all the browsers I'm using are showing at 100% so I know it's not a zoomed in/out issue.

This is a somewhat unrelated note and you don't need to answer this, but the site loads a little bigger on Firefox than my design perimeters were in Photoshop, so there is a tiny but that makes it too high and a scrollbar appears. I'm thinking of reworking the code so it'll re-size for people's viewports properly since I've now learned that there really isn't a standard height. I'm not sure where to start with this, I guess I should use percentages? If anyone knows a good tutorial or a site with information to get me started making a flexible layout, that would be much appreciated!!

Comment: You know that Modernizr should be in the `<head>` and GA before the closing `</body>` element, don't you? If not, [H5BP](http://html5boilerplate.com/) is an excellent ressource for looking those kind of things up. And if you're going to rewrite, you should definitely follow responsive web design rules (e.g. by using some of the frameworks out there like (Bootstrap)[http://getbootstrap.com/], [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), [Gumby](http://gumbyframework.com/), …).

Answer (score 0):

Using the mouse to adjust text size:

a) Click the "Control the current page" button.

b) Select "Text Zoom".

c) Select "Larger" or "Smaller", or "Normal" to make text the default size.

Using your keyboard to adjust text size:

a) To make the web page text size larger: Ctrl + + on the numeric keypad (hold down Ctrl and press +), or Ctrl + = on the main keyboard

b) To decrease the text size: Ctrl + -

c) To return to the default font size press Ctrl + 0

Comment: I already said I know I'm at 100% for both browsers. I've now checked with other computers and it's showing up tiny on a good number of them, and I can't exactly tell visitors to zoom in on the page